# Does $X \subseteq \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ non-countable and $F_{\sigma}$ imply that $X$ contains a perfect set?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I think that the claim below is true, but whenever I try to prove it, I find myself using the continuum hypothesis ($\aleph_1 = \mathfrak c$).

My question: Can the following statment be proved without using CH (continuum hypothesis)?

> Let $X \subseteq \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ be a non-countable set which is $F_{\sigma}$. Does this imply that $X$ contains a perfect set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $X$ is an uncountable Borel set of a standard Borel space (e.g. Baire space), then $X$ includes a perfect set.

You should be able to find the proof in any standard descriptive set theory book.

Comment: A simple argument is that one of the closed sets witnessing $X$ is $F_\sigma$ is uncountable, and so we only need the result for closed sets (this has been proved here a few times). With a bit more effort, we can even eliminate the small dependence on choice that the sketch in this comment uses.